# I have a Selenium script and GUI. How can I share with my team if they haven't downloaded Selenium

Tags: java, windows, selenium, google-chrome

I have a Selenium script and GUI that I created. I took the script's JAVA file, made a GUI for it that allows users to create specific scripts based on their input. I recently made this executable (using JSmooth) and it works perfectly when I use it with my credentials (I have Selenium downloaded locally).

How can I share with my team if they haven't downloaded Selenium? I have systemProperties pointing to the path where Selenium chromeDriver is downloaded on my computer, so of course it works for me. I want to allow everyone in my team access to use this GUI with their user-data-directory automatically found on run-time. Is this possible?

For example:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
   "C:/Users/######/Downloads/chromedriver1.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments(my user-data-directory)
```

I can provide code and other details upon request.

Comment: you can give a readme file or put it as the first page of the GUI to guide other member how to download chromedriver which is compatible with their local browser to a unify folder as default path.  And you can supply a config file for user to customize the chromedriver path,  user can choose to download to the default path or any folder but config the path in the config file.  And in your java code, you will firstly to check the driver exist in default folder, if not exist, you will read the path from config file, If also can'f find driver,  give a tip to user.

Comment: You can supply  this url https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads, in readme to help to know the compatible driver version for browser.   Or you can make a compatible list from above url and add into readme in case public network not accessable

Comment: You can always create a `mega-jar` that contains all dependencies, and even the chromedriver executable. Ugly, but whatever. And big. Like lot of MB. But it can work as a last resort. If you use maven, check out the assembly plugin. Otherwise check the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on your team members not downloading and installing what is required for it to run, you'll have to put your automation tests onto 'Jenkins' and host on a server(we use AWS) they'd be able to see the output of the tests but would not be able to see the browsers processing the tests.

Ultimately though, to answer your question, you can *share* the files with anyone, they can look at them but cannot execute them without the correct dependencies.

[Link to Jenkins Setup Guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html)

This is used for a difference usage than what you are wanting to use it for, but it's probably the only actual way to do what you want to do.